# Checkbox value from database in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the information of several users in the database that I want to edit. Among the information, there is a field named role, which is in the form of a check box and has a value. Now, when I enter the editing page of that user, I want the check box on the page to be filled with the previous value to give it a new value, on the other hand, the value is in the form of a string, that is, the value of the checkbox is defined as a string. The code I typed has errors and does not work properly. please help me

```
@model ERP.Models.EditViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ویرایش - فرم ثبت";
    List<Role> Roles = ViewData["Roles"] as List<Role>;
}

<div class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm  my-1 mx-3">ویرایش در سطح استان</div>
<h6 class="my-3"><img src="~/icons/grid-icon.png" class="mx-2" />فرم ویرایش</h6>
<form asp-controller="Management" asp-action="RegisterationProvince" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="row p-0 mt-2 mb-0">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="row m-0 p-0">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="nationalCode" class="control-label">نام کاربری :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input asp-for="nationalCode" class="form-control" maxlength="10" readonly/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="nationalCode" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="row m-0 p-0">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="userPass" class="control-label">رمز عبور :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input asp-for="userPass" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="userPass" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row p-0 mt-0 mb-0">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="row m-0 p-0">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="ReuserPass" class="control-label">تکرار رمز عبور :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input asp-for="ReuserPass" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="ReuserPass" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="row m-0 p-0">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="fName" class="control-label">نام :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input asp-for="fName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="fName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row p-0 mt-0 mb-0">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="row m-0 p-0">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="lName" class="control-label">نام خانوادگی :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input asp-for="lName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="lName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="row m-0 p-0">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="gender" class="control-label">جنسیت :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input asp-for="gender" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="gender" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row p-0 mt-0 mb-0">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="row m-0 p-0">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="employmentStatus" class="control-label">وضعبت استخدامی :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input asp-for="employmentStatus" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="employmentStatus" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row m-0 p-0">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label>نقش پرسنل :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                    @foreach (var item in Roles)
                    {
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkoption" name="SelectedRoles" value="@item.RoleTitle" @((Model.userRole.Any(r=>r.Equals(item.RoleTitle) ? "checked" : ""))) /> @item.RoleTitle
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row p-0 mt-0 mb-0">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="row m-0 p-0">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="workingStatus" class="control-label">کارکرد :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input asp-for="workingStatus" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="workingStatus" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="row m-0 p-0">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="insuranceStatus" class="control-label">وضعیت بیمه :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input asp-for="insuranceStatus" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="insuranceStatus" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <div class="row p-0 mt-0 mb-0">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="row m-0 p-0">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="score" class="control-label">امتیاز :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input asp-for="score" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="score" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="row m-0 p-0">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="tel" class="control-label">شماره تماس :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input asp-for="tel" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="tel" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row p-0 mt-0 mb-0">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="row m-0 p-0">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="maritalStatus" class="control-label">وضعیت تاهل :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input asp-for="maritalStatus" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="maritalStatus" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="row m-0 p-0">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="address" class="control-label">نشانی محل سکونت :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <textarea asp-for="address" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    <span asp-validation-for="address" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-12 d-flex justify-content-center my-3">
            <input type="submit" value="ثبت" class="btn btn-primary w-25" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

}
```

There is a bug in this part of the code :

```
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
                    @foreach (var item in Roles)
                    {
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkoption" name="SelectedRoles" value="@item.RoleTitle" @((Model.userRole.Any(r=>r.Equals(item.RoleTitle) ? "checked" : ""))) /> @item.RoleTitle
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkoption" name="SelectedRoles" value="@item.RoleTitle" checked="@(Model.userRole.Any(r => r.Equals(item.RoleTitle)))" />
```

Comment: I want to return the previous value in the edit form, but when I delete the extra part that you specified, nothing is displayed in the edit form.

Comment: The `@item.RoleTitle` you had after the `input` tag does not need to be removed.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" class="checkoption" name="SelectedRoles" value="@item.RoleTitle" @((Model.userRole.Any(r=>r.Equals(item.RoleTitle)))) /> @item.RoleTitle

Comment: I want the checkbox values to be checked with the previous value

Comment: If `Model.userRole` collection has any item that is equal to the `RoleTitle` then that checkbox will be checked.

Comment: But it is not checked

Comment: https://github.com/Jimmys20/SO75965421

Comment: Is it possible that Equals can't work because the RoleTitle values are in non-English language?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Try maybe `Equals(item.RoleTitle, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: It displayed this error: 
Error CS0176 Member 'object.Equals(object?, object?)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference;

Comment: <input type="checkbox" class="checkoption" name="SelectedRoles" value="@item.RoleTitle" checked="@(Model.userRole.Any(r => r.Equals(item.RoleTitle, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)))" />

Comment: It gave the same error again